# Crontab do not run the php command

Tags: php, linux, symfony, cron, beanstalkd

I am using Symfony 3 framework with pheanstalk php library. I run the app on server with Linux Debian Jesse. The job creation works ok and if run the worker from terminal it works like it should. But when I added the command to crontab I see that the command do not work. There is not any log in /var/main/user to help me with debuging. I will be very glad for any help.

**This is my worker command (only the execute function):**

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $output->writeln("\n<info>Beanstalk worker service started</info>");
    $tubes = $this->getContainer()->get('app.job_manager.power_plant')->getTubes();
    if ($input->getOption('one-check')) {
        // run once
        foreach ($tubes as $tubeName) {
            if ($tubeName != "default") {
                $this->getContainer()->get('app.queue_manager')->fetchQueue($tubeName);
            }
        }
        $output->writeln("\n<info>Beanstalk worker completed check and stoped</info>");
    } else {
        // run forever
        set_time_limit(0);
        max_execution_time(0);
        while (1) {
            foreach ($tubes as $tubeName) {
                if ($tubeName != "default") {
                    $this->getContainer()->get('app.queue_manager')->fetchQueue($tubeName);
                }
            }
        }
        $output->writeln("\n<info>Beanstalk worker stoped</info>");
    }
}
```

**This is my app.queue_manager function to get job from queue and run command:**

```
public function fetchQueue($tubeName)
{
    if ($this->pheanstalk->getConnection()->isServiceListening()) {
        while (true === is_object($job = $this->pheanstalk->watch($tubeName)->ignore('default')->reserve(self::WATCH_TIMEOUT))) {
            $data = json_decode($job->getData(), true);
            $this->worker($data);
            $this->pheanstalk->delete($job);
        }
    }
}
```

**And the worker to run command**

```
public function worker($data)
{
    $application = new Application($this->kernel);
    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    $parameters = [];
    $parameters['command'] = $data['command'];
    foreach ($data['meta'] as $key => $param) {
        $parameters[$key] = $param;
    }

    $input = new ArrayInput($parameters);
    $output = new NullOutput();

    return $application->run($input, $output);
}
```

**This is my crontab that do not work:**

```
@reboot /usr/bin/php /var/www/mose-base/bin/console beanstalk:worker:start
```

**I created another cron tab that works ok. It works every 15 min, and the difference is that do not have infinite loop (while(1)) so it goes only once thru tubes and than finished. But it is not what i want. I want infinite loop that works all the time like I created it with first crontab:**

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/mose-base/bin/console beanstalk:worker:start --one-check
```

Comment: Put the job startup in something else - like rc.local.  From what I read, the @reboot only happens on a reboot, not a full power down.

Comment: I tried this too. But it it the same. I see the comand running with ps -eLf but the command do not run because the jobs are not deleted and executed...

Comment: Is the program failing because theres no 'input' stream - i.e. no console to open/read from?

Comment: I personally wouldn't use your command! This example [Beanstalk producer, consumer and worker command example in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/frgb/beanstalk-producer-consumer-and-worker-command-example-in-symfony) seems to be doing what you're trying to do. Also as far I can see, you can just copy+paste command `JobProcessorCommand` class without changing it at all.

Comment: Then in your crontab `*/15 * * * *           cd /into/your/application/path && php app/console  --env=prod beanstalk:worker:start ...... and your arguments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used rc.local. It solve the problem. Tnx FreudianSlip

Answer (score 0):

If it works in the console, it doesn't work for your file user permissions. Check it.

You can report your error by email with this job

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/mose-base/bin/console beanstalk:worker:start --one-check 2>&1 | mail -s "mysql_dump" example@mail.example
```